# What is the symbol on Kakashi's ninja dogs' backs?

Tags: naruto, symbolism

Every one of Kakashi's ninja dogs has a symbol on its back that looks like a face:

[image: Pakkun and the symbol on his back]

**What is this symbol and what is its meaning?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a pretty interesting explanation... In this wiki for [Ninken](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Ninken) (Ninja dogs):

> They all have a face-shaped design on their backs called **Henohenomoheji** (へのへのもへじ) — which is the sound made when all the characters in the face are put together. Appropriately enough, children use this design as the face for their scarecrows, which is *"kakashi"* in Japanese.

Basically, if you consider the picture you included:

- The **eyebrows** are the Hiragana へ (he);
- The **eyes** are the Hiragana の (no);
- The **nose** is the Hiragana も (mo);
- The **mouth** is another へ (he);
- The **head shape** (kind of distorted) is the Hiragana じ (ji).

So, へのへのもへじ (henohenomoheji). The first "heno" is repeated because you have a pair of eyes and eyebrows.

Comment: I wonder if they took this into account when naming Kakashi. +1 answer!

Comment: Or rather, if they took Kakashi's name into account when designing his summons.